# SenTestingKit setUp and tearDown overrides get called twice

Tags: sentestingkit, kif-framework, kif

I am using KIF to test our iOS app.  I am trying to make some tests that will go before and after my whole test sweet.  I made a SenTestSuite category and overrode -setUp and -tearDown:

```
 -(void)setUp
 {
     [tester loginCurrentVersion];
     NSLog(@"setup");
 }

 -(void)tearDown
 {
     [tester logoutFromAnywhereIfNeeded];

     NSLog(@"teardown");
 }
```

These methods do get called, but my problem is that they both get called twice.  I can't access any of the `SenTestSuite.m` methods.  I am unsure why they are getting called twice.  Why is it doing this and how can I solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Using a category to override a class's methods is really, really iffy. Instead, subclass SenTestCase and put your `-setUp` and `-tearDown` there. Then have your test classes inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using KIF, your setUp and tearDown methods should be the beforeAll and afterAll. I also suggest you to take a look at the sample application and try to understand those tests.